# C++ How to link LibCurl in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, libcurl

I just downloaded a zip file from LibCurl's official site. In it there are 4 folders: include, bin, lib and samples. I know I need to link my VS2010 project with them. I linked the  include folder but I can't find how to link the **lib** folder. And in it there are files with extension **.A**. Is this normal? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: .A are probably Linux libraries. You need to download Windows build

Comment: You don't link gcc libraries to Visual Studio. You need a Visual Studio build 2010 library.

Comment: Here is some build instructions for libCurl in Visual Studio 2010. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/Using-libcurl-with-SSH-support-in-Visual-Studio-2010.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I got it to compile with some warnings. I used that tutorial - http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/using-libcurl-with-visual-c-2010/ There are many files to be linked....

Answer (score 1):

Under Project Properties -> Linker - > Input - > Additional dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps:

1. Make sure you download the Windows version, not Linux, as @MartinPerry mentioned (as `.A` is a Linux file).
2. Add its `include` folder to your VS2010 include paths: `Proprieties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories`.
3. Add its `lib` folder to your VS2010 library paths: `Proprieties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories`.
4. Add all the `libs` you linked to `Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`.

If it still doesn't work, you may also need to:

**5. Add its `bin` folder to your VS2010 executable paths: `Proprieties > VC++ Directories > Executable Directories`.

---

**Edit**: The above steps should work for many 3rd-party libraries for VS in Windows.